# Unicode Text content changes using Java

Tags: java, unicode

Using Sms Gateway http api works fine while sending unicode text ,

i.e. Unicode for `नमस्ते`:

```
%26%232344%3B%26%232350%3B%26%232360%3B%26%232381%3B%26%232340%3B%26%232375%3B
```

If I am sending this Unicode on below API provided by SMS gateway in a browser.

```
http://msdgweb.mgov.gov.in/esms/sendsmsrequest?username=*****&password=****&smsservicetype=unicodemsg&content=%26%232344%3B%26%232350%3B%26%232360%3B%26%232381%3B%26%232340%3B%26%232375%3B&mobileno=*****&senderid=****
```

Text i received on phone is: `नमस्ते`:

While using same API in Java, I tried with UTF-8 Unicode, Text is coming same as `%26%232344%3B%26%232350%3B%26%232360%3B%26%232381%3B%26%232340%3B%26%232375%3B`.

I am missing something on my application code side?

Comment: ... for people wondering, the so-called "Unicode" in the text is urlencoded `&#2344;&#2350;&#2360;&#2381;&#2340;&#2375;`.

Comment: what is `URF-8` ?

Comment: its utf-8  i tried with utf-8

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "नमस्ते";
```

Somehow the text was translated to HTML entities:

```
&#2344;&#2350;&#2360;&#2381;&#2340;&#2375;
```

This can happen when an HTML form is posted to a server that does not state it accepts (say) UTF-8 (Unicode). Then the browser translates the input field.
Also state in the form:

```
<form action="..." accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Then this string was URL encoded, `&` to `%2B` etcera.

As patch to reconvert HTML entities (`&#1234;`) either use Apache common:

```
s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML(s);
```

Or convert yourself:

```
String convertHtmlEntities(String s) {
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\&#(\\d{1,7});");
     Matcher m = patter.matcher(s);
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
     while (m.find()) {
         int cp = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
         String ch = new String(new int[] { cp }, 0, 1);
         m.appendReplacement(sb, ch);
     }
     m.appendTail(sb);
     return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @joop , can you please tell what unescapeHTML is for ?

Comment: To translate HTML entities, here of the form `&#12345;` to real characters. You would need to add the apache commons library to the project. Hence alternatively the `convertHtmlEntities` function.